# Rxjava 2 combineLatest error

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, observer-pattern

I want to collect the first emissions from two method calls which can be achieved using combineLatest of Rxjava 2 but I am getting confused with the syntax

```
    Observable<Boolean> buildUseCaseObservable(Params params) {
    List<Observable> list = new ArrayList<>();        
    list.add(this.userRepository.fetchUserData());
    list.add(this.masterDataRepository.fetchLov());

    //I think the problem is in the syntax
    return Observable.combineLatest(list, new BiFunction<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(Boolean aBoolean, Boolean aBoolean2) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("FetchRegistrationData complete " + aBoolean + " " + aBoolean2);
            return aBoolean && aBoolean2;
        }
    });

    /* this works fine but it waits for onComplete() of both calls
    return Observable.zip(
            this.userRepository.fetchUserData(),
            this.masterDataRepository.fetchLov(),
            new BiFunction<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(@NonNull Boolean aBoolean, @NonNull Boolean aBoolean2) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("FetchRegistrationData complete " + aBoolean + " " + aBoolean2);
                    return aBoolean && aBoolean2;
                }
            });*/
     }
```

Comment: how about .firstOrError()?

Comment: Please read the method signature of that particular `combineLatest` method.

Comment: I think .firstOrError() gives first item emitted by a single Observable. I have a list of Observables(two in particular).

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the number of observables by using the `take()` operator. That means that once both observables emit a value, the `combinerFunction` will compute a result and the observable will complete.

```
return Observable.combineLatest(
  this.userRepository.fetchUserData().take(1),
  this.masterDataRepository.fetchLov().take(1),
  combinerFunction)
```